# Convexity of KL-Divergence $D_{\text{KL}}(p \| q_{\theta})$ in $\theta$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, information-theory

The Kullback-Leibler divergence (DKL)

$$D_{\text{KL}}(p \| q_{\theta}) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p \log \frac{p}{q_{\theta}}$$

is definetly convex in the parameters $\theta$ of the PDF $q_{\theta}$, if the PDFs $p$ and $q_{\theta}$ are in the exponential family.
Because then it can be shown, that the DKL is the Bregman divergence $D_{\text{B}}(q_{\theta} \| p)$ which is convex in $\theta$ ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bregman_divergence), [ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family#Relative_entropy) and sec. 13.12.7 in [ref](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~siva/705/lec13.pdf)).

**But how can I show that DKL is convex in the parameters $\theta$ of $q_\theta$, if $p$ is not in the exponential family?**

I thought about the following reasoning:

1. The maximum likelihood estimaton (MLE) $\theta^*=\text{argmax}_{\theta} \sum_n q(x_n | \theta)$ with $x_n \sim p$ is concave in $\theta$, if the proxy $q_\theta$ is in the exponential family (13.2.3 [ref](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~siva/705/lec13.pdf)). This is because in MLE we always assume that $x_n$ is drawn from $q_{\theta^*}$ instead of $p$.
2. In the limits ($n\rightarrow \infty$), the MLE becomes the DKL with $\lim_{n \rightarrow \inf} \text{argmax}_{\theta} \sum_n q(x_n | \theta) = \text{argmin}_{\theta} D_\text{KL}(p \| q_{\theta}) $ ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation#Relation_to_minimizing_Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence_and_cross_entropy))
3. Given 2., the DKL is convex in the parameter space $\theta$ for any $p$ (even if it is not in the exponential family), because we haven't constrained MLE regarding the distribution $p$ from which the samples $x_n$ are drawn.

Is this reasoning correct and/or does there exist a better formal definition why $D_\text{KL}(p \| q_{\theta})$ is convex in $\theta$?

Note: Some [remarks](http://www.herbrich.me/papers/KL.pdf) which I found useful which give an example in eq. 2.3 and 2.4, if $q$ is Gaussian.

Comment: I think you're fine, but this seems very convoluted. Perhaps an easier way would be to just assume that $q$ is in the canonical form, and break up the expression a little. You'll end up with a term independent of $\theta$, a term that's linear in $\theta$, and the log-partition function. This means that the convexity of the KL divergence w.r.t. $\theta$ is really is a question about the convexity of the log-partition function of the exponential family in canonical form - it has nothing to do with what $p$ is.